# VB.NET ComboBox, setting the right "value"

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm working on a hobby project where I will store Sail Boats, Skipper, Clubs, Races and Results. A Skipper is a person that is a member in a club.

So I have table with persons (skippers) and a table with clubs.

I have created an DataGridView where I have the person and the id to the club. I have also added a ComboBox with clubs. When I click on a row I want to load the person into several TextBoxes and also set the right club in the ComboBox, but I can't find how.

[image]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim MyRow As DataRow


    myTable = FillCluTable() <== Get clubs into a DataTable

    MyRow = myTable.NewRow
    MyRow(0) = 0
    MyRow(1) = "Sel"
    MyRow(2) = "Select Club"

    myTable.Rows.InsertAt(MyRow, 0)
    cbxClubs.DataSource = myTable



    cbxClubs.DisplayMember = myTable.Columns("ClubName").ToString
    cbxClubs.ValueMember = myTable.Columns("Id").ToString
    cbxClubs.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: This is how the code looks like when I click on a row

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
cbxClubs.DisplayMember = "ClubName"
cbxClubs.ValueMember = "Id"
```

Delete the part with MyRow and build the Table header from the designer page